# DynamicObject<JSArray>@31160c66' cannot be passed from one context to another

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Got an error when try to pass an array (from a JSON.parse) to a normal array

'DynamicObject@31160c66' cannot be passed from one context to another. The current context is 0x76a5839d and the argument value originates from context 0x5a09aee1.

Also tried to use Array.from method.

Two arrays to be equal

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON had extra brackets [ ], had to remove the extra [] and convert it to an array.

Comment: If the issue was just a typo, you should close it as not reproducible instead of posting an answer